# how to remove empty quotes and outer curly braces from json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse large text file that has multiple JSON line by line but I'm not sure how do I remove empty `""` `:` and outer curly braces in python. Below is my JSON -

```
  {
      "": {
        "appName": "Test",
        "pageOffset": "0",
        "pageLimit": "50"
      }
    }
```

Expected -

```
    {
        "appName": "Test",
        "pageOffset": "0",
        "pageLimit": "50"
      }
```

Comment: If your original document is in a variable named `item`, looks like you want `item[""]`. Don't think about what you're trying to remove as "quotes and curly braces", focusing only on the document's textual syntax; instead, think about the semantic objects that syntax represents (your object is in a dictionary with a single key/value pair, with an empty string as that key).

Comment: ...that said, when you say "line-by-line"... is this document all on one line in the real thing? When folks are writing streams of JSON documents in the real world at-scale and trying to be polite about it, they usually use a delimiter (which is where formats like JSONL come from -- one JSON document per line).

Comment: I have bunch of similar json line by line in one text file

Comment: Good -- that's what I read the text to mean, but your samples showing content split out across multiple lines conflicted with that textual description.

Comment: i beautified the json format for this post

Comment: Not my downvote but: That two different answerers can't agree on what you want strikes me as evidence that the question is unclear. "unclear" is one of the two marquee downvote reasons (the other being "not useful").

Comment: ...if you [edit]ed the question to make it clear enough that the answer you aren't accepting is _obviously wrong_, that would be a less-ambiguous question. (Normally, edits that invalidate answers are frowned on here, but if that edit salvages the question from being of poor quality, that's a corner case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution is just to check whether if there is any key with an empty string and if there is return it

```
data = {
      "": {
        "appName": "Test",
        "pageOffset": "0",
        "pageLimit": "50"
      }
    }
res = {}
for x, y in data.items():
    if len(x.strip()) == 0:
        res = y
    else:
        res[x] = y
print(res)
```

Comment: Why would you iterate on `y.items` and add them to `res` individually instead of just returning `y` and not needing to construct a new object at all? (Similarly, for any other object, one can just return the object unchanged; again, not needing to construct anything new).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy I didn't noticed that

Answer (score 1):

```
Dict = {
  "": {
    "appName": "Test",
    "pageOffset": "0",
    "pageLimit": "50"
  }
}

Dict[""]

#OUTPUT

# {'appName': 'Test', 'pageOffset': '0', 'pageLimit': '50'}
```

Comment: This is not what an OP wants

Comment: @Gad, how precisely is it not what they asked for? `{'appName': 'Test', 'pageOffset': '0', 'pageLimit': '50'}` is _exactly_ what they say they want (well, they show the desired output in JSON format rather than Python, but still, it's a match; your competing answer doesn't coerce the output back to JSON either).

Comment: User can append the relevant output, as in json format we have nested dicts so user can exract each dictionary with key

Comment: @CharlesDuffy an OP want to remove the keys with an empty string not to get key with an empty string

Comment: @Gad, you're inferring those requirements, but I don't see anywhere they're explicitly stated. All they're _stating_ they want is removal of the `{"":` text from the beginning of each JSON document, and the `}` text from the end. This answer accomplishes that.